# How to enable vsync in DirectX10

Tags: windows-7, directx, slimdx, directx-10

I'm working on a apps that's based on DirectX10 by using SlimDX. I would like to enable vsync similar to DirectX9, but the fps doesn't seems to lock to 60Hz(which happens if I'm using Direct9). I'm setting vsync by using this

```
SwapChain.Present(1, PresentFlags.None);
```

Did I do something wrong?

Btw, I'm running Win7 with ATI HD5570 video card. After some googling, I gather that ATI can force vsync on certain games. So I wonder if that's related.

Reference for code to C++ will do as well. I'll translate it myself.

Thanks

Comment: I also notice that the output is sluggish, after some digging, I found that DWM's memory actually hit 1GB, it goes up in 200~300MB increment, then drops back to less than 100MB. That's why the output of my apps skips. Maybe that's I'm getting less than 60Hz. Any idea what's affecting DWM? My apps only display a rotating square mesh with a picture in it. that's all, non-full screen

Comment: I've found out that I can set the refresh rate at ModeDescription when I'm creating the swap chain. But it still doesn't stick to 60Hz

Answer (score 1):

First argument of SwapChain.Present is syncInterval. 0 indicates that presentation should occur immediately, without synchronization. Any other value indicates that presentation should be synchonized with the specified next vertical blank.
So use it like this:

```
SwapChain.Present(0, PresentFlags.None);
```

Comment: Supposingly it should work as published, but it doesn't on my machine with ATI 5570HD. I've read some post point to problem of ATI with certain driver version, but I'm not sure if mine is affected.

Comment: Have you tried running pix to verify actual value of presentation interval and swap chain desc or other structures?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee417062%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try to force vsync using Catalyst Control Center

[image]

Comment: Ive' done that too. Still doesn't lock. It's either fluctuating higher than 60, or fluctuating between 50 to 60.